# Fixed-Effects Correlated with Another Dummy

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model, observational-study, economics

Question regarding convention in econometrics.

Suppose I am running a two-way Fixed Effect (FE) model on a District-Year panel. Year varies from 2000 to 2010. Suppose I want to examine the effect of an exogenous shock, say *x*, that occurs in 2005 and the exogenous shock occurs in all districts.

That is, for all districts, *x = 1* if *Year < 2004* and *x = 0* otherwise.

Clearly x is perfectly co-linear with my Year FEs, even after dropping a year dummy (say, 2000).

What is the correct (conventional) way to deal with this issue? Should I drop the Year FEs all together? Or should I drop an additional Year dummy (say 2001)?

Assume that Year FEs control for a substantial portion of variance (i.e. there are substantial district-invariant year-to-year shocks).

Thanks!

Comment: So, the year is a factor (in R parlance)? Could you give the data types of all your involved input variariables?

Comment: The independent variable is violence (murders per capita), and in 2005 a new country-wide restructuring of the police force occurs. This is the exogenous shock.  There are, however, country-wide key events in certain years like electoral violence, which I would like to control for using Year FEs.  Problem is that the 10 Year dummy variables (2001-2010) are perfectly co-linear with the exogenous shock since it also is a  country-wide event. This is even after dropping the Year 2000 FE.